# Is it possible to create a Enum in Swift with Raw Values type of a Closure?

Tags: swift, enums

As I tried following code, I get some Errors.

```
enum Operate: ((Double, Double) -> Double) = {
    case Plus = {$1 + $0}
    case Minus = {$1 - $0}
    case Multiply = {$1 * $0}
    case Divide = {$1 / $0} 
}
```

Is it possible to create a Enum in Swift with Raw Values type of a Closure ?
Thanks.

Comment: [Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID149) I guess the answer is no.

Comment: If the future, please be sure to actually include any errors your getting in the question itself.  It may have been completely irrelevant here, but given that you're here to ask a question, it's best to provide as much detail as possible.  Additionally, it improves search results and may help identify duplicated questions.

Answer (score 7):

As @Pang said, only Strings, Characters or any integer of floating-point number types can be used as the raw type. However, you could achieve something similar using a `struct`:

```
struct Operate {
    typealias OperationType = (Double, Double) -> Double

    static let Plus : OperationType = { $0 + $1 }
    static let Minus: OperationType = { $0 - $1 }
    // ...
}

let plus = Operate.Plus
plus(1.0, 2.0) // 3.0
```

Comment: That obviously compiles, but I'm not sure it does what the OP wants, which is presumably an `enum` variable that holds (& returns) the correct closure selected at `init` time - something that he could put into a more complex structure like `struct CalculatorButton { var button: UIButton; var operate: Operate }`
Perhaps the OP can clarify what he was attempting?

Comment: I agree, it would be good if the OP could clarify. If they are intending to store an operation; one option would be to store a closure of `OperationType` and use the `Operate` class to dispense operations. However, this would not be an appropriate solution if the OP needs to compare operations.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible way, but using `enum`:

```
typealias TwoOp = (Double, Double) -> Double

enum Operate {

    case Plus, Minus // etc...

    var op: TwoOp {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Plus:
                return {$1 + $0}
            case .Minus:
                return {$1 - $0}
            }
        }
    }
}

let opPlus = Operate.Plus
let answerP = opPlus.op(3, 2)
let opMinus = Operate.Minus
let answerM = opMinus.op(3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The raw value can't be a closure, but there is another option for enums.

Enums support an associated value that can hold any type you want. You could use an associated value to store your closure. Take a look at the Swift Language iBook for more information on enum associated values.

Answer (score 1):

As @Duncan C pointed out instead of creating an `enum` with raw types, you can create an `enum` where each case has an associated value as follows:

```
    private enum Operation {
            case BinaryOperation((Double, Double) -> Double)
            case UrinaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
        }
```

The type of the associated value goes in brackets next to each case. Unlike raw values, associated values can be closures.

You can then create a variable of type Operation with an associated value of type `(Double, Double) -> Double`:

```
let plus = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 + $1})
let minus = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 - $1})
let multiply = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 * $1})
let divide = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 / $1})
let plus = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 + $1})

let abs = Operation.UrinaryOperation({abs($0)})
```

and use them:

```
plus(3.0,2.0) //5.0
abs(-4.0)     //4.0
```

Comment: This type of logic is super useful for creating a calculator app!

Comment: I don't think you meant `Urinary`Operation :)